# Apache spark slave nodes don't connect to master node but workers do start

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have 5 nodes (1 master and 4 slaves). I have the same config files (`slaves` and `spark-defaults.conf`) on all machines indicating master and slave hosts.

When I start Apache spark using `start-all.sh` command, workers start on all machines but in webUI panel there is only one worker (on master node).

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my problem solved.
i had to set `SPARK_MASTER_HOST` and `SPARK_MASTER_PORT` environment variables manually. after adding these two to `.bashrc` file problem solved and slave nodes are now connected to the master node.